# Как писать: НИ или НЕ?

Tags: не-или-ни

Рассудите или поправьте меня, прошу.
На одном из форумов я написала, цитирую: "Уже НИ в первой вашей статье читаю... вижу...". Имея в виду, что ни в первой, ни во второй, ни в третьей...
И вот в комментах меня начинают исправлять, что надо писать "НЕ".

Answer (score 5):

Даже если бы вы написали то, что имели в виду, вас всё равно поправили бы, поскольку далее следует *утверждение* "читаю... вижу":

> Уже **не** в первой, **не** во второй (и) **не** в третьей вашей статье [= ваша статья такого содержания *по счёту* уже четвёртая или пятая, а ***не*** первая, вторая или третья] я **читаю**... о том-то.

С *отрицанием* вышел бы другой грамматический случай:

> **Ни** в первой, **ни** во второй, (и) **ни** в третьей вашей статье [= ни в одной и них] я **не** нашла убедительных сведений об этом.

Здесь нельзя было бы сократить начало предложения до "*ни в первой*", "подразумевая" остальное, - для упрощения можно только обобщить: "*ни в одной... не*". В вашем же случае с **не** сокращение возможно.

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что правильно **"Уже НЕ в первой вашей статье читаю... вижу...".**

Давайте от сути. Если опустить некоторые детали, то НЕ - частица отрицательная, а НИ - усилительная. Из этого и надо  исходить.

> "Уже НИ в первой вашей статье читаю... вижу...".

Думаю, что у вас ошибка. Хотелось, конечно, фразу целиком... Но, судя по всему, вам верно ответили. У вас же прямое отрицание, а не усиление. 
"Не в первой" означает, что статья, где вы что-то там читали - **не первая.**
То есть вторая, третья...

А вот что может значить "ни в первой" в вашем случае сказать трудно. "Ни" означало бы усиление, а что тут усиливать-то, если отрицания нет.
Вообще очень трудно найти корректную фразу с НИ, которая бы не имела еще и НЕ - явного или подразумевающегося, причем при глаголе (сказуемом, обычно, реже с причастием).

*Для любителей казуистики. Попытался было найти хоть какое-то обоснование для НИ - нету его. Ни одна, даже самая фантастическая, фраза в ваших параметрах не получается.*

*Вот  самое близкое: "Ни в первой вашей статье **читать** не хочу, ни во второй..." С личной формой не получается никак.*

**UPD**
Нашел-таки. Корявенько, но возможно.

***Ни в первой вашей статье читаю, ни со второй знакомлюсь - нигде не вижу оправдания для такой орфографии.***
Для разговорной речи, думаю, допустимо, хотя для сколько нибудь высокого стиля оба НИ тут просто лишние. Но ручаюсь, ничего подобного вы не могли иметь в виду из-за изысканности самой конструкции.

Answer (score 1):

**Уже НЕ в первой вашей статье читаю..**

Выбор отрицательной частицы НЕ можно объяснить тем, что **здесь присутствует скрытое противопоставление**: уже не в первой статье, а в третьей, четвертой и т.д.